# Time complexity of a recursive algoritm that divides the problem in n^(1/2) subproblems

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory

I am learning time analysis of algorithms and I have a question about the following problem:

Let's say we have a problem size of n and we can use an algorithm that solves the problem by dividing it into n^(1/2) subproblems (each has size of n^(1/2), recursively solving each subproblem, and then combining the solutions in linear time.

My target is to find the time complexity of this algorithm. I believe that I have to solve one of these two recursive equations : T(n) = n^(1/2) * T(n^(1/2)) + n, T(n) = n^(1/2) * T(n^(1/2)) + O(n).  However I do not know which one. Could you tell me the differences between those two?

Comment: So, your question boils down to what O(n) means?

Comment: I know what O(n) means. I do not wich is the difference  between those two equations. A part of me says that they are the same but I am not sure

Comment: It is safe to say that in your case they are the same, put 2n instead of n and watch how T(n) becomes 2T(n) which means that multiplying n by a constant multiplies T by a constant but it is all big O notation so it does not matter.

Comment: I guess in some place the first equation could lead to a term that could be used in a theta notation where as the right equation will lead to a term that could be used only with big O notation (since it is an upper bound).

Comment: You have to solve the second one.  The difference is that "linear" might mean `100 * n`.  That is very much not `n` but is `O(n)`.

Comment: @Yonlif They are not the same.  Linear and `n` do not mean the same thing.

Comment: @Yonlif: Re: "it is all big O notation": That's not true. The whole point is that the first equation does *not* use big O notation.

Comment: I am very familiar with the the difference between Linear and n, what I mean is that - If you will use the T term inside a big O notation (Which, let's be honest, will be), it does not matter which formula are you solving.

Comment: Also when solving this kind of equation to compute time complexity of an algorithm you never really do n operations, you are doing O(n) operations. But again, it does not matter, solve the second one if you find it easier to look at, and at the end put a big (beautiful) O notation.